# How do I write a Lambda statement for this Linq to XML function?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, linq-to-xml

I am working with [this XSD file.](http://www.spiraltechinc.com/Tmats/Tmats_09-2010.xsd)  The portion of the XML that is relevant to this question is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="https://wsmrc2vger.wsmr.army.mil/rcc/manuals/106-11" 
           targetNamespace="https://wsmrc2vger.wsmr.army.mil/rcc/manuals/106-11"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Tmats">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>TMATS G Group</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="ProgramName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>PN</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
```

To get the `documentation` value for a given `xs:element`, I have this small function, which recursively walks the descendant nodes until it finds the `documentation` element:

```
public string GetCode(XElement e)
{
    foreach (var s in e.Elements())
    {
        // If we hit an intervening element, bail out.
        if (s.Name.ToString().Contains("element"))
            return "";

        if (s.Name.ToString().Contains("annotation"))
        {
            // I'll explain this loop in a moment.
            foreach (var t in s.Elements())
            {
                if (t.Name.ToString().Contains("documentation"))
                    return t.Value;
            }
        } 
        else
            return GetCode(s);
    }
    return "";
}
```

So far so good.  The unit test looks like this:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetCodeTest()
{
    string path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\harvey robert\Desktop\Tmats.xsd";

    IEnumerable<XElement> elements =
        from e in XElement.Load(path).Elements()
        select e;

    TmatsDictionary target = new TmatsDictionary(); 
    XElement x = elements.First();
    string actual = target.GetCode(x);
    Assert.AreEqual("TMATS G Group", actual);
}
```

Which passes.  Now I want to extend the test by adding an additional case, like this:

```
    XElement z = elements.DescendantsAndSelf()
                         .First(y => y.Attribute("name")
                         .ToString().Contains("ProgramName"));

    actual = target.GetCode(z);
    Assert.AreEqual("PN", actual);
```

...But **this fails due to a null object reference** (most likely `y.Attribute("name")`).

Did you see the loop in the function above that I commented?

```
// I'll explain this loop in a moment.
foreach (var t in s.Elements())
{
    if (t.Name.ToString().Contains("documentation"))
        return t.Value;
}
```

It's written that way because *I can't figure out how to express the condition in a Lambda statement that works.*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that works.

Notice the call to the `GetName()` method in the `DescendantsAndSelf()` call.  This returns a properly formatted URI-prefixed name of the form `{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element`, which will match correctly to the `xs:element` names.

The result is that `DescendantsAndSelf()` returns only those elements having the name `xs:element`, all of which have attributes associated with them (so there is no chance of a null reference error when referencing the `Attributes` collection).

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetCodeTest()
{
    string path = @"C:\TestArea\Tmats_09-2010.xml";

    IEnumerable<XElement> elements =
        from e in XElement.Load(path).Elements()
        select e;

    TmatsDictionary target = new TmatsDictionary();            
    XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

    XElement z = elements.DescendantsAndSelf(ns.GetName("element")) 
                         .First(y => y.Attribute("name")
                         .Value.Equals("ProgramName"));

    actual = target.GetCode(z);
    Assert.AreEqual("PN", actual);
}
```

Comment: `ns + "element"` should work as well as `ns.GetName("element")`

Comment: @Gabe: Possibly, but it doesn't look right without a `ToString()` call, and that makes it too long. I'll try it tomorrow. Anyway, the `GetName()` call seems to make more sense to me, even though it takes up a few more characters.

Comment: I didn't think that `ns + "element"` would even *work* with a call to `ToString()`, although I suppose it should.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use namespaces:

```
XNamespace ns = "https://wsmrc2vger.wsmr.army.mil/rcc/manuals/106-11";
XElement z = elements.DescendantsAndSelf()
                     .First(y => y.Attribute(ns + "name")
                         .Value.Contains("ProgramName"));
```

Comment: Tried that, still getting the same error. Actually, it turns out that an older version of the XSD didn't have the namespaces in it, so I don't think it is the namespaces, but thanks for pointing that out. The IDE says that it is failing on `.First(y => y.Attribute(ns + "name")`

Comment: @Robert: What's in `y.Attributes()`? What are their names?

Comment: `y.Attributes()` is a bit hard to isolate. However, `elements.DescendantsAndSelf()` returns *all* elements (not just the `xs:element` elements), and most of the non-xs:element elements don't have attributes, which must explain the null reference error. I suspect I need to do something like `elements.DescendantsAndSelf("xs:element").Attribute("name")` ..etc, but if I try that, I get the error, *"The character **:** cannot be included in a name."* *Grf.*

Comment: @Robert: You need to declare an `XNamespace` for `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`, like I did.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
elements.DescendantsAndSelf().
                First(y => y.Attribute(XName.Get("name", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")));
```

Comment: That looks like it will work. Is there a way to get it to globally "XNamespace" in the style that SLaks posted, and still get it to recognize the prefix?  Your way is a lot of typing if I have to do this in many places.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `y.Attribute("name").ToString().Contains("ProgramName")` will fail on every element that doesn't contain a "name" attribute. You need something like this:

```
y.Attribute("name") != null &&
y.Attribute("name").ToString().Contains("ProgramName");
```

If you expect all `<element>` elements to contain a `name` attribute, you can ignore the null check and do this:

```
XElement z = elements.DescendantsAndSelf(
                         "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element")
                     .First(y => y.Attribute("name") 
                     .ToString().Contains("ProgramName"));
```

EDIT: Note that I added the expanded name to include the namespace URL. See if that works.

Comment: That's true, but I'd rather just filter out everything but the xs:element elements (which all have attributes) but to do that, I need to figure out how to assign an **xs** prefix to the thing.

Comment: Saw your edit. `DescendantsAndSelf("element")` will only work if I figure out how to use an **xs** prefix with it.  `DescendantsAndSelf("xs:element")` will not work.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe.  You were right about the expanded name.  I figured out how to get that name from the XNamespace, and I posted the working code here.